# Flutter appbar with image, customized containers and tabbar

Tags: flutter, dart, gesture, tabbar, sliverappbar

The [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEOkE.png) and when [scrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTX7R.png). I have used dependency ***appbar_animated: ^0.0.3*** for this effect, so when user scrolls then the image and my custom container which has info about the restaurant disappears and it becomes a normal app bar. Now the **problem** is I want a tabbar below all of these like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szxzp.jpg) and when user scrolls the tabbar  attaches to the appbar like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AENN4.jpg).

**In Summary i want this**

[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MENeN.gif)

**This is my code so far**

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'package:appbar_animated/appbar_animated.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_getx/widgets/expanded_restaurant.dart';

class TalabadScreen3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const TalabadScreen3({super.key});

  @override
  State<TalabadScreen3> createState() => _TalabadScreen3State();
}

class _TalabadScreen3State extends State<TalabadScreen3> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: ScaffoldLayoutBuilder(
        backgroundColorAppBar:
            const ColorBuilder(Colors.transparent, Colors.white),
        textColorAppBar: const ColorBuilder(Colors.white),
        appBarBuilder: appbar,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                "img/cover.jpg",
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.31,
                ),
                height: 900,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.22,
                left: 10,
                right: 10,
                child: restaurantInfoContainer(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**I have also tried this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgQ81.png)** and when scrolled [scrolledScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDkAS.png). The problem with this is that i don't know how to add background image when expaned and how to place my *`restaurantInfoContainer`* .

**this is the code:**

```html
class SliverTabExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const SliverTabExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SliverTabExampleState createState() => _SliverTabExampleState();
}

class _SliverTabExampleState extends State<SliverTabExample>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final _tabs = List.generate(10, (index) => 'Tab#${index + 1}');

  late final TabController _tabCont;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabCont = TabController(length: 10, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  bool isVis = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (_, __) {
          return [
            SliverAppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              scrolledUnderElevation: 0.0,
              elevation: 0,
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    size: 30,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              actions: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 28,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: IconButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.ios_share_rounded,
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 28,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: IconButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      weight: 0.001,
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ],

              expandedHeight: 300,
              // collapsedHeight: 100,

              pinned: true,
              floating: false,
              // title: Text('TabBar Example'),
              centerTitle: true,
              bottom: TabBar(
                controller: _tabCont,
                isScrollable: true,
                tabs: [
                  ..._tabs.map(
                    (label) => Tab(
                      child: Text(label),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabCont,
          children: [
            ..._tabs.map(
              (label) => SamplePage(
                label: label,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually solved the problem without using third party dependencies. I have used `flexibleSpace:` of `SliverAppBar` to place restaurant's cover photo and my customContainer(restaurantInfoContainer).

**This is the solution:**

```js
class TalabadScreen3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const TalabadScreen3({super.key});

  @override
  State<TalabadScreen3> createState() => _TalabadScreen3State();
}

class _TalabadScreen3State extends State<TalabadScreen3>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final _tabs = List.generate(10, (index) => 'Tab#${index + 1}');

  late final TabController _tabCont;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabCont = TabController(length: 10, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (_, __) {
          return [
            SliverAppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              scrolledUnderElevation: 0.0,
              elevation: 0,
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    size: 25,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
                  background: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(
                        "img/cover.jpg",
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.18,
                        left: 10,
                        right: 10,
                        child: restaurantInfoContainer(),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
              actions: [
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.ios_share_rounded,
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      weight: 0.001,
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ],

              expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
              collapsedHeight: 70,

              pinned: true,
              floating: false,
              // title: Text('TabBar Example'),
              centerTitle: true,
              bottom: TabBar(
                controller: _tabCont,
                isScrollable: true,
                tabs: [
                  ..._tabs.map(
                    (label) => Tab(
                      child: Text(label),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabCont,
          children: [
            ..._tabs.map(
              (label) => SamplePage(
                label: label,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```